# How to play .h264 file from IP Camera?

Tags: h.264

My security camera https://www.aliexpress.com/item/High-Quality-HD-720P-Wireless-IP-Camera-Wifi-Night-Vision-Camera-IP-Network-Camera-CCTV-WIFI/32270499536.html?spm=2114.13010608.0.0.0ptGKR stores every 15 minutes a .h264 file that I don't know how to properly open it
- The H264 demux mode of VLC player does not show the timestamp
- The SMPlayer shows the timestamp, but would does not have the progress bar/handler: so I cannot move to a certain time. Also it stops after 9 minutes while the video is 15 minutes.

File is here: http://www.filedropper.com/0435381000076777420912

Any idea how to play that file ?

Comment: Try converting it to mp4 w/ avconv -i input.h264 -vcodec copy output.mp4

Comment: H264 elementary streams don't  have a timestamp.